# How to trigger the pipeline of a git submodule in the main pipeline in GitLab?

Tags: git, gitlab-ci, pipeline, git-submodules

I have a main repository with a defined pipeline at `.gitlab-ci.yml`. When I push changes to the repository this runs few tests at the main repository.

I have also few sub-projects (libraries) that are linked as sub-modules. The sub-modules have their own pipeline tests. And if I do changes on the main these changes might break the sub-module, but the sub-module pipeline only triggers when there are new commits on the sub-module.

I would like to trigger the pipeline of the sub-module inside the main project when there are changes on the main. What is the easiest way to do that?

Comment: Finally I managed to do it with the following Git documentation page: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/ (using curl)